# Wget Bash Script File Not Found

Tags: bash, git, wget

I have the following script:

```
for i in {1..16}; do
$wget http://url/$i.jpg -O C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/
done
```

Saved the file as test.sh and run it within Git on windows.

The files are live on the server but when I run the script i get "No such file or directory"...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is substantially correct if not for the character `$` that you have to delete and for the file name that you have to repeat

```
for i in {1..16}; do
   wget http://url/$i.jpg -O C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/$i.jpg
done
```

Indeed the option `-O` asks to write the filename and not the directory.

> -O file
>     --output-document=file
>   The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.

**Some words more**
In your version `$wget` is a variable never assigned and so empty.
The result of the command inside the cycle becomes, for example,

```
http://url/1.jpg -O C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/
```

that is a file not present on your HDD.

To investigate errors of this kind you can add an `echo` in the line and see the output generated by your cycle:

```
for i in {1..16}; do
   echo $wget http://url/$i.jpg -O C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/
done
```

it will reveal your problem/mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Made me re-read my code and realized my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

My -P directory had not been created so wget didn't have a place to download the files to.

Needed to change -O to -P. Added "" for the directory location.

This is now working

```
 for i in {1..16}; do
 wget http://url/$i.jpg -P "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Test"
 done
```

Also needed to ensure the formatting was correct in Notepad++. Changed EOL Conversion from windows to Unix.